# React Component is not showing in Rails 5.1 App with Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack

I have a Rails 5.1 app using React via Webpacker and I have had other components work ok, but the last one I'm trying is not showing in the page. I get no errors, and the react-dev-tools in Firefox doesn't detect a React app.

I've doubled checked whether I've missed an import or export, but can't see an error there.

**app/javascript/packs/roastsapi.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import RoastFeed from 'RoastFeed'

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', function () {
  var element = document.getElementById("roast-feed-component");
  ReactDOM.render(<RoastFeed />, element);
});
```

**app/javascript/RoastFeed/index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'

class RoastFeed extends React.Component {
  // State:
  // { loading: true }
  // { loading: false, planet: { name, climate, terrain } }
  // { loading: false, error: any }
  state = { loading: true };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://swapi.co/api/planets/5")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        planet => this.setState({ loading: false, planet }),
        error => this.setState({ loading: false, error })
      );
  }

  renderLoading() {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  renderError() {
    return <div>I'm sorry! Please try again.</div>;
  }

  renderPlanet() {
    const { name, climate, terrain } = this.state.planet;
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{name}</h2>
        <div>Climate: {climate}</div>
        <div>Terrain: {terrain}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return this.renderLoading();
    } else if (this.state.planet) {
      return this.renderPlanet();
    } else {
      return this.renderError();
    }
  }
}

export default RoastFeed
```

**app/views/roasts/index.html.erb**

```
//...
<div id="roast-feed-component"></div>
//...
```

Comment: I'm not sure what might be the error, but the documentation is good for webpacker-react, it documents using Turbolinks, and also provides a nice Rails helper for rendering your React components: https://github.com/renchap/webpacker-react

Answer (score 0):

Your webpacker was not configured to support jsx files.
In webpacker.yml file under extensions add `- .jsx`